# Spring Cloud Stream - Using TestChannelBinderConfiguration with StreamBridge

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to test StreamBridge with TestChannelBinderConfiguration ?
Or there’s something I don’t understand...

I have a test like this :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MockConfig.class })
@Import({ TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class })
class NotificationPushEventProducerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    OutputDestination outputDestination;

    @SpyBean
    NotificationPushEventProducer producer;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<Message<NotificationPushEvent>> msgNotifCaptor;

    @Configuration
    static class MockConfig {

    }

    @Test
    void testSendingMessage() {

        // @formatter:off
        NotificationPushEvent notification = NotificationPushEvent.newBuilder()
                .build();

        StepVerifier.create(this.producer.sendNotificationPush(notification))
            .expectNext(true)
            .verifyComplete();

        Message<?> receive =  this.outputDestination.receive(3000, "fact.notification.push");

        assertThat(receive).isNotNull();

        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

And inside the producer i do this :

```
this.streamBridge.send(BINDING_NAME, msgNotif)
```

The message `receive` is always `null`

How can i do to "link" `StreamBridge` and `ChannelBinder` ?